# Stumped translating 女の戯言を真に受けられちゃ迷惑だって

Tags: translation

A man has fallen in love with a mobster’s girlfriend and it’s mutual.  Though threatened by the mobster’s minions, he refuses to let go of her.  For the sake of his safety, the mobster’s girlfriend has to break it off with him by telling him she does not love him – which she does after the following 2 lines (which are spoken by someone urging her to do it):

> お前から言ってやっておくれよ

I translate this as: You have to say it.

> 女の戯言を真に受けられちゃ迷惑だって

I’m not quite sure what to make of this, but I think it’s something like:
He has to believe a woman’s bullshit story. 
(which doesn’t look right at all!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think she is saying : "It's bothersome for you to believe I was being serious with my fooling around".

Or more accurately in English by reading between the lines :

> You thought I was serious with you? I was just fooling around! Don't be such an annoyance and leave me alone already!

That is just my guess though, I might be wrong.

Comment: `That is just my guess though, I might be wrong.` -- いや、あってると思います。＾＾

Comment: Just to clarify, since it's followed by the quotative particle って, this whole thing is what the guy is telling the girl to say.

Comment: Should it written as 『女の戯言を真に受けられちゃ迷惑だ』って or are the quote marks made unnecessary by the って?

Comment: @Noob the brackets are used around citations in proper written Japanese, but って is far from that. It is very casual and mostly used when talking, not writing.

Answer (score 1):

> お前から言ってやっておくれよ

Command form 「くれる」: "You be the one to tell him."

> 女の戯言を真に受けられちゃ迷惑だって

I'd read this as 「だって」 rather than 「って」、 which would have the mobster commenting on the chump's supposed gullibility rather than telling her what to say. But, even in English, mobsters don't really care what they say, so we shouldn't try too hard to pin it down.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd read the second sentence like this:

女の戯言を真に受ける     "To accept as truth the joking words of a woman"

女の戯言を受けられる     The れる form here is the "passive of adverse effect" with direct object, as in 財布をぬすまれた, "I had my wallet stolen". So this means "I [suffer the adverse consequences of having] my woman's frivolous words accepted as truth"

女の戯言を真に受けられては [> れちゃ] 迷惑だ  "Having my frivolous words, those of a woman, taken seriously, is irksome"

って = といって "say"

So this piece of advice means "Say to him 'It's annoying to have my frivolous woman's words taken as true'"

A bit more idiomatically: "Tell him what you said was just a woman talking light-heartedly and you're annoyed that he took it seriously"

Comment: 英訳がきれい・・・　φ(..)ﾒﾓﾒﾓ　あっホントだ Indirect Passive (Suffering Passive) 全然気づかなかった。。。

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down like that. The contractions can be quite a challenge.